# Nav Controller Toolbar Parent-to-Child Navigation

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-jetpack

I am using the Jetpack nav controller along with [Side Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).

My MainFragment.kt looks something like this:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_home_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_home" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.widget.MaterialDrawerSliderView
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My fragment A has a recyclerView which has a onclick listner to open another fragment:
Adapter.kt

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
  Log.d("Clicked", object.name)
  v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FragmentA_to_FragmentB,null,navOptions)
}
```

But I need a way to change the toolbar from hamburger icon to cross.

I have been trying different approaches but cannot find a way to get this sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [`setupWithNavController()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar).setupWithNavController(androidx.navigation.NavController,%20androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout)) function within your `Fragment`

```
toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(), root)
```

This will setup the drawer and toolbar listener for you.

Comment: I already have the toolbar and drawer setup and is working. But i want to change the hamburger icon to a cross on one of the fragments. So for example: Fragment A (hamburger) -> Fragment  B (hamburger) -> Fragment C (cross - back to fragment B)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavController.html#addondestinationchangedlistener)

The idea is that the hosting activity or whoever is hosting that toolbar would listen to the changes and then update the icon accordingly